# Moderation Plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

It's the first time for me using pgfplots. I have to build a moderation analysis plot as the following one. Could you please help me with that? Unfortunately I can not provide the coordinates. "Low gender" means Men, and "high gender" means Women.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE! I suspect that your "moderation analysis tool+" ia actually M$ excel. For drawing with `pgfplots` it can serve only for data source. So, if you like to get help here, please show with Minimal (not)Working Example , what you try so far in LaTeX and where you suck. MWE is complete document, which can be compiled.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could figure most of this out by looking through the manual for a bit (there are a *lot* of examples in there),  but here's one suggestion.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  symbolic x coords={Low age,High age},
  xtick=data,
  ymin=1,ymax=6,
  enlarge x limits=0.5,
  legend entries={Low gender, High gender},
  legend pos=outer north east
  ylabel=Dependent variable
]

\addplot coordinates {(Low age,2)(High age,2.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(Low age,2.2)(High age,2.9)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]